# GET request works in Postman, fails in browser

Tags: node.js, express

As per the title, and now including my full routes for help in getting this working.

When I submit a get request to /api/users/resetpassword/:resetLink from Postman it works. When I send the exact same link (And same resetLink) in a browser it does not.

No errors about CORS, or anything for that matter appears.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('config');
require('dotenv').config(); 
const app = express();

// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// DB Config

const db = config.get('mongoURI');

// connect to mongodb

mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Use routes

// app.use('/api/items', require('./routes/api/items'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
// app.use('/api/bookings', require('./routes/api/bookings'));

// Serve static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set Static Folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Catchall route launched. Oops");
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

/routes/api/users.js

```
const express = require("express");
require('dotenv').config();
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const config = require("config");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const _ = require('lodash');
// Item model
const User = require("../../models/User");

// @route POST api/users
// @desc register new user
// @access  Public

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log('router.post"/"');
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  // Simple Validation
  if (!name || !email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Please enter all fields" });
  }

  // Check for existing user
  User.findOne({ email }).then((user) => {
    if (user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User already exists" });

    const newUser = new User({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });

    // Create salt & hash
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save().then((user) => {
          jwt.sign(
            { id: user.id },
            process.env.JWT_SECRET,
            { expiresIn: 3600 },
            (err, token) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              res.json({
                token,
                user: {
                  id: user.id,
                  name: user.name,
                  email: user.email,
                },
              });
            }
          );
        });
      });
    });
  });
});

// @route PUT api/users/forgotpassword
// @desc Activate token and email user
// @access  Public

router.put('/forgotpassword', (req, res) => {
  console.log("router.put('/forgotpassword'");
  // console.log("Here is req.body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body))
  const { email } = req.body;
  if (!email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Please enter all fields" });
  } else {

    // Find existing User by email address
    User.findOne({ email }).then((user) => {
      if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "That email doesn't exist with us..." });
      const payload = {
        id: user._id,
      }
      const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
      const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, {
        expiresIn: '15m'
      });

      const newLink = {
        resetLink: token,
      }
      // Take resetLink and implant it into user record
      user = _.extend(user, newLink);
      user.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Something went wrong..." + err });
        } else {
          // Begin mailout function
          // Removed

          const fullResetLink = process.env.CLIENT_URL + "/api/users/resetpassword/" + token;
          console.log("Link: " + fullResetLink)
          return res.status(200).json({ msg: `An email has been sent to ${email} with further instructions. Try clicking here though: ${fullResetLink}` })
        }
      })
    })
  };
});

// @route PUT api/users/resetpassword
// @desc Take link from email and reset password
// @access  Public

router.get('/resetpassword/:resetLink', (req, res) => {
  console.log("router.get('/resetpassword/:resetLink'");
  const { resetLink } = req.params;
  console.log("resetLink? " + resetLink);
  // verify the reset link is genuine
  jwt.verify(resetLink, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, decodedData) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Incorrect token or it is expired. " + err });
    } else {
      User.findOne({ resetLink }, (err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) {
          return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User with this token doesn't exist" });
        } else {
          // Success condition. Go ahead and allow the form to appear to reset the password
          console.log("Hi there, you made it! " + resetLink)
          return res.status(200).json({ msg: "I like what you got, good job!" })
        }
      })
    }
  })
});

router.put('/resetpassword/:resetLink', (req, res) => {
  console.log("router.put('/resetpassword/:resetLink'");
  const { resetLink } = req.params;
  const { newPass, newPassMatch } = req.body;
  if (newPass !== newPassMatch) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Passwords don't match, please try again." })
  }

  if (resetLink) {
    jwt.verify(resetLink, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, decodedData) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Incorrect token or it is expired." });
      }
      User.findOne({ resetLink }, (err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) {
          return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User with this token doesn't exist" });
        }
        // My god you better hash this
        console.log("newPass is: " + newPass)

        bcrypt.hash(newPass, 10, (err, hash) => {
          console.log("Hash is: " + hash);

          const obj = {
            password: hash,
            resetLink: ''
          }

          user = _.extend(user, obj);
          user.save((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Reset password error" });
            } else {
              return res.status(200).json({ msg: "Your password has been changed." });
            }
          })
        })
      })
    })
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "Authentication error!" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Only the router.get route in users.js is failing, and none of the console.logs are appearing ever, which makes me think it never fires. Can't work out why. The router.put directly below it works perfectly from within Postman or on the frontend.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It Could caused by cors. Have you tried to enable this in your application?

Comment: Sadly no, installed CORS, changed the route to router.get('/resetpassword/:resetLink', cors(corsOptions), (req, res, next), but no success. Still nothing.